# How can I show that the amount of multiplications in $n \choose {k}$ is in $O(log(n))$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first thing I'd need to do is creating a term equal to $n \choose k $ just using multiplications. 
Then I need to show that the amount of multiplactions isn't exceeding $O(log(n))$.

But I'm missing out onto both parts. Do you have an idea? Or at least some starting help for me.

*I already figured that due to [Exponentation by Squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) it is possible to do this with $x^n$. That's why I feel like there has to be a way for $n \choose k$ aswell.*

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202554/how-do-i-compute-binomial-coefficients-efficiently

Comment: @u1571372 thanks! I guess that helps. I will definetly get some sleep now and try to solve it with reference to the thread. But I'm still not sure if I can do it.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301885/calculate-value-of-n-choose-k

Comment: What makes you think that an O(log(n)) solution is even possible ?